# ClassNotFoundException: Server

Tags: java, filepath

I have a problem as mentioned in my Title. What I'm trying to do is to compile my Server class and execute it when my main class is running.

This is my runServer method in my main class

```
    public static void runServer() throws Exception{

    File sourceFile = new File("/Users/Joel/NetbeansProjects/FYP/src/ui_v2/Server.java");
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileMgr = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    fileMgr.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File("/Users/Joel/NetbeansProjects/FYP/src/ui_v2")));

    compiler.getTask(null, fileMgr, null, null, null, 
            fileMgr.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(sourceFile)));
    fileMgr.close();

    try {
        Class params[] = {};
        Object paramsObj[] = {};
        Class thisClass = Class.forName("Server");
        Method thisMethod = thisClass.getMethod("main", params);
        thisMethod.invoke(thisClass, paramsObj);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

This is a screenshot of the files inside my `ui_v2` folder.
[image]
And this is my error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Server
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
at ui_v2.GenerateChat.runServer(GenerateChat.java:353)
at ui_v2.GenerateChat.Btn_ConfirmActionPerformed(GenerateChat.java:230)
at ui_v2.GenerateChat.access$000(GenerateChat.java:26)
at ui_v2.GenerateChat$1.actionPerformed(GenerateChat.java:129)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

As you can see, the mentioned Server.class is in the folder as written in the file path in `sourceFile`. So I have no idea what isn't my current code working and instead giving me an exception.

Comment: Is ui_v2 one of the places whree Java looks to find classes (i.e. is it on the classpath)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `Class.forName("Server")` your classpath should be set to ui_v2 folder otherwise you need to give the name with package till classpath is set. say your classpath is set to src you need to give path like
`Class.forName("ui_v2.Server")`

**UPDATE :-**  Also main method is not called in right fashion. It should be

```
Method thisMethod = thisClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
thisMethod .invoke(null,  params);// static method doesn't have an instance
```

you can pass params as null if you don't wanna pass any parameter

Comment: Hmm but i set the location at `"/Users/Joel/NetbeansProjects/FYP/src/ui_v2"`. Then shouldn't my `Class.forName("Server")` be correct?

Comment: Javadoc for [`forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) states the class name must be fully qualified. In your case the fully qualified name is `ui_v2.Server`.

Comment: also you set the "/Users/Joel/NetbeansProjects/FYP/src/ui_v2" so that compiler finds it but while execution jvm will look for this under classpath

Comment: Ok the class is found. But now it says `NoSuchMethodException`. This is so weird.

Comment: This error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ui_v2.Server.main()` appears.

Comment: @MSach Hmmm. I tried the second solution but now it gives off `java.lang.NullPointerException` error. I have no idea what causes this.

Comment: Probably null pointer inside your main method. That you need to debug

Comment: @MSach Alrighty, Thanks man for all the help. Really appreciate it ^^